# Multiple accounts in Outlook, only want to send through one

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

At the moment, whichever account's Inbox or folder you're in when creating a new email, Outlook wants to send the email from that account. I only ever want to send from the one particular account though (the others are monitored only, not to be used for sending emails).

The account I want to use for outgoing email is set as the default in Account Settings - is there any way of making sure this is the one Outlook always sends through?

Alternatively, is there a recipe for an Outlook rule that will stop the email if I haven't noticed that I'm sending it through one of the wrong accounts?

Using Outlook 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Best I've been able to come up with myself is a rule that delays sending for two hours when sent through a no-outgoing account, in the hope that I'll notice I've sent from the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

With some VBA you can check which account is sending.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If item.SendUsingAccount <> "main@company.com" Then
    MsgBox "Sending from wrong account. Send action will be cancelled."
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Alt + F11 to open up the VBA editor.
Paste into the ThisOutlookSession module